# What are some good practices avoid mixing HTML with the dynamic contents

Tags: html

I know very little about programming but I came across and old script written in PHP that generates the pages the browser renders using something like

```
print stdhead('Home') . $HTMLOUT . stdfoot();
```

The `$HTMLOUT`variable is being built by PHP dynamical then gets sent along with the footer and the header to the browser to render. 
The problem with this way as I see it (from a novice point of view) is that the `$HTMLOUT` variable is huge, contains LOADS of HTML tags, variable in length and components which makes understanding the script an impossible mission for beginners like myself. 
The script has been written in 2009, I would expect that now-days there is way to separate HTML from the variables of the server-side language, which languages demonstrate such practices?

Comment: Languages don't. Templates do. See also the MVC pattern.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you see this? In a project at work, something open source, a tutorial? This could have been a requirement, developer preference, or technical restriction...

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tbdevnet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these days your concept is very complaicated , There is a MVC techniqe which separates Model / View / Controller from each other .

My advice is don't output all your HTML as one var , Separate everything , May be one word , sentence or block like

echo $uername

This will generate one or two words only.

echo topicComment()

This will generate a whole topic comment .

And so , Everthing has to be encapsulated in methods which also encapsulated in class and so on .

HTML code may be separated on functions / methods also .. 
And the database is in the background reply for your view queries .

You have to read more about MVC techniqe